# How to find the distribution of players on each individual player's latest rank in SQL

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression

I have a table whose attributes are the following;

| user_id | date | start_rank | end_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xggghgh | 2019-02-02 | 01 | 25 |

I want as my output the following table;

| user_id | latest_rank | No_of_players_on_the_latest_rank |
| --- | --- | --- |

I thought that perhaps I'll be able to get the desired output using cte. So, I was able to make a cte using the following code;

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,  
        MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id) AS max
    FROM
        table
)
```

The reason for taking the `max(date)` is that the latest rank will be on the latest date.

But I don't understand how do I approach the remainder of the problem. Perhaps my approach will not lead me to the output that I desire.

How do I get there?

Comment: first tag always your rdms, second can a user have multiple entries per date?

Comment: How is `latest_rank` computed?

Comment: `No_of_players_on_the_latest_rank` is just a `JOIN ON "rank"` with `SELECT "rank", COUNT( DISTINCT user_id ) FROM table GROUP BY "rank"` - but you haven't told us how to derive those `rank` values yet.

Comment: @Dai latest rank is the end_rank of a player for his max(date)

Comment: @nbk Yes, a user can have multiple entries for one date

Comment: So if different rows share the same `user_id` and `date` values, which `end_rank` should be used?

Comment: @Dai Good point, the date is actually a timestamp. Which I failed to mention. So consider latest rank corresponding to the maximum of the timestamp

Comment: without an hour:minute_second:.millisecond, you can't determine which entry was the latest

Comment: @nbk please consider it to be a timestamp

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use MySQL as redms, as you don't mentioned which you are using
Further u assume, that the latest can be determined by the date column, which you said is actually a timestamp

This approach determines first the latest entrys for every user, and in the following select it selects those determined by their row number and in a sub select it count the distinct user_ids, with  out the user that has the endpoints

> ```
> WIth CTE AS(
> SELECT `user_id`, `end_rank`, 
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY `date` DESC) rn
> FROM table1
> )
> SELECT `user_id`, `end_rank`
> , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM table1 WHERE `end_rank` = c1.`end_rank` AND `user_id` <> c1.`user_id`) No_of_players_on_the_latest_rank
> FROM CTE c1 WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | end_rank | No_of_players_on_the_latest_rank
> :------ | -------: | -------------------------------:
> xggghab |       29 |                                1
> xggghgh |       25 |                                0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc8c5d5a4dd8911c8602ccc3d299f285)*

Comment: Thank you @nbk . I cannot upvote, for I don't have the required reputations. Could you please explain the need for "where rn = 1"?

Comment: rown_number 1 is the row that has the latest date entry, `ORDER BY `date` DESC` determines the order , if you want to understand it better run the query from CTE alone and see the rn numbers, that should explain everything

Comment: I did that, thank you @nbk :)